# Liferay 6.2 - ORA-00972: identifier is too long for Notifications portlet

Tags: notifications, liferay-6

I'm facing a problem with the notification portlet in my Liferay Portal Community Edition 6.2 CE GA4.
I'm using Oracle DB and driver ojdbc6.jar (Version 11.2.0.3.0).

When I click to open Notifications I see the number of them  (in db table, column DELIVERΕD have value = 1 for these notifications) but in tomcat logs I get exception `ORA-00972: identifier is too long`.
I'm getting the same exception when I use java methods to create my own custom notification.

Although those notifications are created in the table USERNOTIFICATIONEVENT correctly.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a known issue, on this page   https://web.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/49168570 there is a solution which is to compile the plugin yourself, because the solution is on the source Code, but a new version of the plugin wasn't published.

On one of the answers a user also uploaded a compiled war, but if I were you I'd try to compile myself.

Regards.